# Sending Variables Between iPhone Controllers

Tags: iphone, android, objective-c, controller, android-intent

I am currently in the process of switching from Android to the iPhone SDK. I have a TableView where the user selects an item. I am having trouble passing data between controllers. Is there an equivalent to the Android's `startActivityForResult` or putting extra's into Intents? Like so ...

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Foo.class);
i.putExtra("Foo", foo);
```

Comment: This has been asked several times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: It's as simple as passing data between objects. Just do it ✔

Comment: The big problem I am having is that the user can select alot of options on this view (UISwitch, Buttons etc) but every time i launch a new controller to try to get a selection from the user and i report back all of the UI components are reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this in .h file in ParentViewController

```
NSString *strABC;
```

Make below function in ParentViewController

```
-(void)setString:(NSString *)strEntered{
    strABC=strEntered;
}
```

Now In Post view controller do like this:

```
ParentViewController *objSecond = [[ParentViewController] initwithNibName:@"parentView.xib" bundle:nil];

[objSecond setString:@"Comment Controller"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecond animated:YES];
[objSecond release];
```

Now, In secondViewController viewWillAppear Method write this.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      lblUserInput.text = strABC;
}
```

Please check spelling mistakes as I hand written this. Hope this help.

If you are not using navigationContoller then you can do something like this.

```
SecondViewControler *objSecond = [[SecondViewController] initwithNibName:@"secondview.xib" bundle:nil];
[objSecond setUserInput:txtUserInput.text];
[objSecond viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.view addSubview:objSecond];
[objSecond release];
```